# Date Search in AdvancedSearch functionality : Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, advanced-search

I tried advanced search functionality in alfresco. I couldn't search data with date condition..
I can search using other fields..but not with date   criteria.

How can I search data with date field.

Following is my custom model

**share-config-custom.xml**

```
<config evaluator="model-type" condition="my:test">
        <forms>
            <form id="search">
                <field-visibility>
                    <show id="my:corDate" />

                </field-visibility>
                 <appearance>
                       <field id="my:corDate">
                          <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/date.ftl" />
                       </field>
                    </appearance>

            </form>
        </forms>
    </config>
```

**datatype of my:corDate d:date**

following is advanced search code

```
<config replace="true" evaluator="string-compare" condition="AdvancedSearch">
   <advanced-search>

       <forms>
           <form labelId="search.form.label.cm_content" descriptionId="search.form.desc.cm_content">cm:content</form>
           <form labelId="search.form.label.cm_folder" descriptionId="search.form.desc.cm_folder">cm:folder</form>            
           <form labelId="type.my_test" descriptionId="search.form.desc.my_test">my:test</form>


       </forms>
   </advanced-search>
</config>
```

**customModel.xml**

```
<type name="my:test">
            <title>Test</title>
            <parent>cm:content</parent>
            <properties>
            <property name="my:corDate">
                    <title>Correspondence Date</title>
                    <type>d:date</type>
                    <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    <index enabled="true">
                  <atomic>true</atomic>
                  <stored>true</stored> 
                  <tokenised>both</tokenised>
               </index>
            </property>



        </properties>           
</type>
```

How can I solve this problem..How can I do search with date criteria ?

Thanks

Comment: You have mentioned configuration,please also mention problem also.

Comment: Problem is If I search content using date condition then result not found. If I select date 3/9/2015 then no result found. But I have one document with this date ...